# Streaming PHP file always get cut

Tags: php

I tried to stream an audio file using this PHP code, but always get cut around 3/4 of the file size, especially for iPad and Android agents.

```
ob_clean();
flush();
set_time_limit(0);
$size = intval(sprintf("%u", filesize($filename))); 
$chunksize = 0.5 * (1024 * 1024);
if ($size > $chunksize) {
  $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
  $buffer = '';
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
    echo $buffer;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
  }
  fclose($handle);
} else {
  readfile($filename);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I have tried completely with readfile() only, the result is even worse. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using PHP for this?

Comment: Because my site is using PHP. You have other suggestion?

Comment: How to do that? No pun intended, if you want to answer, please be clear. Otherwise, please better not answer.

Comment: This section is used to get clarification on a post; my question is basically why you must use PHP to serve a file, since a web server is great at that stuff.